# Versioning for major changes

Tags: version-control

A client has asked me for **major** changes in a product I'm making for him. How should I go about with it in my VCS? Should I

- branch
- tag and continue
- start a new project
- or do something else?

Comment: Shouldn't your title ask what to do **before** major changes?

Comment: Hm, completely missed that. I'll use *for*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either d) do something else (like a holiday) or b) tag and continue. If you need to support the current version of the app, then you can create a branch of the tag, and then work on that.

I would only start again if it's a complete rewrite of the product?

Comment: I meant to start again in the versioning: clean the project a bit and then `<vcs> init`.

Comment: Do you mean the product version number?

Comment: No, I mean to start with a new, clean repository.

Comment: Ah! Well if you do then obviously you would lose all version history prior to this version, which is probably unnecessary. Unless it really is effectively a new product.